# Como conectar una base local con una base Remota MySql usando C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite

Tengo una base MySql en un servidor, pero sufre bastantes caidas de conexion, quisiera guardar mas que todo tablas catalogos, y sincronizarlas cuando la conexion este activa,buscando una solucion, que no tenga que instalar tanto programa en la PC del usuario, encontre la sincronizacion con SQLite, pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo o algun ejemplo. Talvez se podrian crear archivos temporales o no se la verdad. Alguien sabe una forma de lograr esto?

Uso C#,MySql y visual studio 2015.

Comment: Hola @hectortetto no he usado nunca la sincronizacion con SQLite , pero una forma sencilla aunque no la mejor es: 1 ) Intentar conectar con la bbd remota si hay conexion => Obtener los datos de la bbd local y luego modificar la remota

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria evalues libreria de sincronizacion como ser

[SQLite-sync.com](https://ampliapps.com/sqlite-sync/)

[SQLite-sync SampleApp](https://github.com/sqlite-sync/SQLite-sync.com/tree/master/amplisync-clients/DotNET%20C%23)

Pero hay un detalle, esta libreria requiere implementar un servicio web al cual se conecta para sincronizar, o sea toma los datoa de la db local y se conecta al servicio que actua de intermediario de la db remota que quiere sincronizar

Hay otras opciones de terceros, pero creo que requiere de licencia para usar la libreria

[dotConnect Sync Framework Tutorial](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/SyncFramework.html)

Si usaras `Sql Server` con `Sql Compact` tienes `Microsoft Sync Framework`, pero para estas dbs que menconas no aplicaria